# symfony1.4-like symfony2 installation

Tags: project, structure, generator, symfony

symfony1.x followed a good standart that the whole framework lies somewhere outside and is available to any project. Today I started to read symfony2 documentation and actually downloaded the 'with vendors' 2.0.1 package which is presented on download page. After opening the package I was a bit surprised of what I've seen. But after looking around the package I found that the only folder I need is 'vendors' one - so I copied its content to my '...\lib\vendor\symfony2' folder (near '...\lib\vendor\symfony' and '...\lib\vendor\ext'). I added it to include path and proceed reading documentation. And then I found a problem - a command listed 'php app/console generate:bundle --namespace=Acme/HelloBundle --format=yml' produced simple questions. Did they miss to explain how to generate a project (structure, preconfiguration, command-line files, etc)? And what about '.bat' and '.sh' files?

Answer (score 1):

Symfony2 is very, very different than symfony 1 - especially when it comes to the directory structure. You can't simply drop in the vendors dir and expect it to work. [This page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_big_picture.html) explains how to setup a new Symfony2 project.

Comment: Actually it shows how to add some functionality to a precreated default project... what about creating an absolutely new one from the ground? There is no way to generate the base dir structure via command line tools?

Comment: Everything you need to know about setting up a Symfony2 project is in the docs - http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to forget Symfony... and to think with Symfony2 about another think completely different than S1.

Installation is really simple and you will need some advanced PHP knowledge just to understand how it works... But if you have worked with S1, I expect you will have not much problems :)